# WP_query and pagination?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have to get some custom post types and need to do that with WP_Query (query_posts doesn't work).

How can I do the pagination? Whatever I tried didn't work... any help would be awesome I can't crack this alone...

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
    array(
    'author' => $user_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxtype',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'delicious-food',
    )
) 
); 
$answer_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//// Loop trough the results

while ( $answer_query->have_posts() ) : $answer_query->the_post();

//// do something

endwhile;
```

Comment: Add the `paged => 1,2...n` argument, and I think that `posts_per_page`, as well as `paged` should be outside of the `tax_query` array.

Comment: Thanks yeah just did this, now I can limit the posts. Thats a first step!

Comment: Did you add `paged` and set it to the page number you are looking for?

Comment: I did set it but with it can just pick what page I want and can't get the pagination to work. I use the regular wordpress next_posts_link(); function for the pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could tell us what you're exactly trying to achieve, we can help you better!

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
               'post_type' => 'question',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'paged' => $paged,
               'author' => $user_id
            );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($my_query->have_posts()):
    while($my_query->have_posts()):$my_query->the_post();
        //Loop goes here...
    endwhile;
    //support for page-navi plugin, please refer readme.txt for further instructions
    if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
    {
        wp_pagenavi();
    }
    elseif ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link() )
    {
        ?>
        <div class="wp-navigation clearfix">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php //next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php //previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?></div>
        </div>
<?php } //if wp_pagenavi
endif;
?>
```

Check [WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) for more parameters.

Btw, `query_posts` also works with custom posts, as it takes all the parameters that you can pass to WP_Query.

Comment: Thanks Ruwick. I just want to get all the posts from a custom post format called questions and this custom post format has different categories that are defined as custom terms. With the query above I can get the latest posts for a certain custom term but can't get pagination to work.

Comment: Have you installed WP-Pagenavi? I skipped that part, check the new code in my answer. I have added the pagination part.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes it works now. I modified the code a bit and used the code from layotte down here now. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-pagination-to-a-wp_query-loop?replies=16

Comment: Great job man! :)

Answer (score 3):

IF you change the `$my_query` to `$wp_query` it should work. The code in the internal wordpress functions `next_posts_link` & `previous_posts_link` expect the query object to be called `$wp_query`.

Comment: By doing this you also clobber the main query which can result in unintended consequences. Can you edit the answer to explain how to avoid that problem? Also, it is best to post plausibly working code in the answer.

Comment: wow.. what a great tip!