# Custom URL for all posts in Wordpress

Tags: blog, frontpage

I have a wordpress site with static page as the front page. I want to have `/blog` to display the recent posts. How can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) with a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), then create a custom [WP_Query object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to return your last posts.

You can get something like:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/
get_header();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any', #all post types
    'posts_per_page' => 10 #get 10 posts
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()):
  while($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
    the_title(); #display the title
  endwhile;
endif;

get_footer();
```

Comment: No need to `wp_reset_postdata()`, as it's a custom `WP_Query` object.

Comment: i will try this one. How about the paging?

Comment: These two questions will help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31298/wp-query-and-pagination and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/multiple-wp-query-loops-with-pagination